# Why doesn't this cause a fork bomb

Tags: recursion, fork

This program prints 2^3 times hi and exits
Isn't it that fork call calls main function recursively?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    puts("hi");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It's not recursive and it doesn't keep forking indefinitely.  That's why it doesn't fork bomb.  Fork doesn't cause `main` to be called.  What fork does is create a copy of the current process state and return 0 *from the fork call* to the child copy and the process id to the parent.

Walking through your program, it creates exactly 7 copies of the original, making for a total of 8 calls to `puts("hi")`.

```
original   copy 1    copy 2    copy 3    copy 4    copy 5    copy 6    copy 7 
fork 1 --> created
fork 2 ------------> created
fork 3 ----------------------> created
"hi"                           "hi"
            fork 2 --------------------> created
            fork 3 ------------------------------> created
            "hi"                                   "hi"
                     fork 3 -------------------------------> created
                     "hi"                                    "hi"
                                         fork 3 ----------------------> created
                                         "hi"                           "hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

You answered it yourself. fork() does not call main(). One process calls fork() but two processes return (well, we're assuming no error)

So, fork()-1 is called, and returns twice (one in parent, one in child).  They both move to the next statement.

Then fork()-2 is called twice (one in parent, one in child) and both calls return twice, again, one in parent(s) one in child(ren).

Then fork()-3 is called, this time 4 times, and 8 returns.  They all print, and you get all the 'hihihihihihihihi' sent to your screen.

Please look at the man page for [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).